# How can I set up RAID 0 on a ASUS P5QL PRO motherboard?

Tags: bios, raid

I've got a computer with a **motherboard** which has the following text as product information on the invoice:

> Asus P5QL Pro Sockel 775 Intel P43 max.
>   8GB DDR2-1066 ATX 1xPCI-E 16x 3xPCI
>   1xUDMA/100 6xSATA2 **RAID 0** 10xUSB2.0
>   GB-LAN 7.1 Sound

The computer has **two** identical **500 GB** drives:

> Seagate Barracuda 7200.12 ST3500418AS
>   500GB 3.5" 7200U/min 16MB Cache SATA2
>   intern Bulk

I've been told that I can "**set RAID 0 in BIOS**". But nothing the **motherboard manual**, or on the **[motherboard website](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=YYermRswb7n46yAX&content=overview)**, nor when I press **DEL**:

[image]

nor when I press **ALT-F2**:

[image]

mentions anything about RAID.

On the download section (thanks mterwoord), I downloaded the Storage Manager:

[image]

But I'm not sure what I need to do with this exactly to be able to set up RAID.

Here's my BIOS startup screen options, @mterwoord I don't seem to have a CTRL-D:

[image]

In BIOS (F8), I was able to switch the drives from IDE to AHCI, but upon rebooting it doesn't give me a new Storage Manager option, just the same DEL, F8 and ALT-F2. When I go into BIOS (F8), I can now get to AHCI Settings but there is nothing there about RAID:

[image]

When I try to install Windows 7 again, it still recognizes two drives, so I assume RAID isn't set. All I am trying to achieve is to **make my system faster** and I understand that RAID 0 will do this. Will the fact that I have AHCI set give me a speed increase without explicitly setting RAID?

**How can I set up RAID 0 on a ASUS P5QL PRO motherboard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in windows.

In the bios you can set the SATA controller mode. Default on most motherboards is (was?) IDE compatibility, as windows xp/2003 didnt support native sata.
You should set it to RAID/AHCI. Then the intel ich option appears after the boot screen.

Please note that changing the sata controller mode will stop your os from functioning (most of the time)

The EzFlash thing is for flashing your bios. you need to be in the first screen, i think in the Advanced section.

Regards,

Matthijs ter Woord (mterwoord)

Answer (score 1):

The marked answer is incorrect. The P5QL PRO motherboard does not have RAID as it uses the P43 chipset. Intel has RAID functionality **disabled** on this chipset.